# Map<String, String>, how to print both the "key string" and "value string" together

Tags: java, dictionary, key

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the concept of Maps.

I have came up with the code below. However, I want to print out the "key String" and "value String" at the same time.

```
ProcessBuilder pb1 = new ProcessBuilder();
Map<String, String> mss1 = pb1.environment();
System.out.println(mss1.size());

for (String key: mss1.keySet()){
    System.out.println(key);
}
```

I could only find method that print only the "key String".

Comment: `System.out.println(key + ", " + mss1.get(key) );`

Comment: One liner with apache.commons.lang.StringUtils: `String message = StringUtils.join(yourMap.entrySet().toArray(), "\n");`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are various ways to achieve this. Here are three.

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("key1", "value1");
    map.put("key2", "value2");
    map.put("key3", "value3");

    System.out.println("using entrySet and toString");
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry);
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("using entrySet and manual string creation");
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("using keySet");
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key + "=" + map.get(key));
    }
    System.out.println();
```

#### Output

```
using entrySet and toString
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3

using entrySet and manual string creation
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3

using keySet
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3
```

Comment: Use Map.Entry instead of Entry

Answer (score 6):

Inside of your loop, you have the key, which you can use to retrieve the value from the `Map`:

```
for (String key: mss1.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + ": " + mss1.get(key));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
final Map<String, String> mss1 = new ProcessBuilder().environment();
mss1.entrySet()
        .stream()
        //depending on how you want to join K and V use different delimiter
        .map(entry -> 
        String.join(":", entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```