# Insert string keyword values based map keys in main string

Tags: java

In Java, I have to insert strings value based on the key in main string.
For example -

Main String -

```
sellers(seller: $sellerId, shipment: $shipmentId)
```

Map of key and value -

```
{
    sellerId: abc
    shipmentId: 123
}
```

So after inserting it will become

```
sellers(seller: abc, shipment: 123)
```

I know i can do string replace. But that doesn't seem to be good approach here. So just wondering is there a standard approach or better way of doing things here?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261075/adding-multiple-entries-to-a-hashmap-at-once-in-one-statement

Comment: May be it is [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35642636/10354810)
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("key1", "value1");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on values map can hold you may face some problems. For instance if value may contain other key identifier like

```
{
    foo: $bar
    bar: 123
}
```

then using series of `replace(mapEntryKey, mapEntryValue)` could change string like

```
abc $foo efg $bar
```

first into `$foo->$bar`

```
abc $bar efg $bar
```

and then `$bar->123`

```
abc 123 efg 123
```

which is NOT what we wanted.

To avoid such problem we should iterate over template only once, search for each `$key` and replace it with value stored for it in `map`. If map doesn't contain such key we can leave it as it (replace it with itself).

We can do it with [`Matcher#replaceAll​(Function<MatchResult,​String> replacer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)). BTW if map value can contain `$` and `\` which are also metacharacters in replacement, we need to escape them. To do it we can use [`Mather#quoteReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)) method.

Demo:

```
Map<String, String> map = Map.of("sellerId", "abc",
        "shipmentId", "123");
String yourTemplate = "sellers(seller: $sellerId, shipment: $shipmentId)";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$(\\w+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourTemplate);

String replaced = m.replaceAll(match -> {
    if(map.containsKey(match.group(1))){
        return Matcher.quoteReplacement(map.get(match.group(1)));
    }else{
        return Matcher.quoteReplacement(match.group());
    }
});
System.out.println(replaced);
```

Output: `sellers(seller: abc, shipment: 123)`.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches you can consider:

1 - loop over map entries, and do a simple string replace (note that this assumes a single occurrence of each var in the strings; if that is not the case, you need to use replaceAll):

```
String text = "sellers(seller: $sellerId, shipment: $shipmentId)";
Map<String, Object> binding = ...;

String result = text;
for (Entry<String, Object> entry : binding.entrySet()) {
    result = result.replace("$" + entry.getKey(), String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
}
```

2 - for advanced use cases, you want to use a proper template engine. And here's an example using [groovy's simple template engine](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html#_simpletemplateengine) (use in java by adding the [groovy jar](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.4.16/jar)):

```
groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine();
Writable template = engine.createTemplate(text).make(binding);

String result = template.toString();
```

Just note that groovy replaces variable names prefixed with `$`, and that's why this works without changes (making this a good choice for your current syntax).

Both produce your expected result, but you have to choose based on what this can turn into.

Answer (score 0):

String format is an option here

```
Map<String, Integer> yourMap = new HashMap<>();
yourMap.put("abc", 123);

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : yourMap.entrySet()) {
   String output = String.format("sellers(seller: %s, shipment: %d)", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
   System.out.println("output = " + output);
}
```